# Merge DataTable functions together

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have the following code which functions as intended:

```
var $datatable = $('#datatable-keytable');
var item = [["myName","myNumber"],
            ["myName2","myNumber2"]];

$datatable.DataTable({
    keys: true
});

for(int i in item) {
    $datatable.DataTable().row.add([
       item[i][0],
       item[i][1]
    ]).draw();
}
```

However I get the error: 
`Cannot reinitialize DataTable` see: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

How can I merge both these functions together to prevent this error from showing up?

Comment: This is a default error. You can not call DataTable twice. You need first to destroy() it before you rebuild it. Anyway it's really unclear what you are trying to do. If you want to add columns to dataTable you normally should do this in your `php` script before you will pass them to the dataTable. Note that this is just a guess, you need to post here your code (php, html,...) if you want us to come up with a reasonable answer. :)

Comment: @Franco the reason the error is showing up is because I have two separate initializations of `DataTable`. I'd like to be able to perform the `.row.add` and set `keys: true` under one `DataTable` initialization.

Comment: This is not difficult to do, please read firs my previous comment and then add some additional code.

Comment: @Franco there is no php in my code and the two columns are generated in my html like so: `<tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr>`.

Comment: Where are you getting these `items` from?

Comment: I've updated my code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought I had deleted an edit I had made to his answer, I've reopened the post, sorry about that.

Comment: @NotToBrag: thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dataTable.api()

> DataTables has an extensive API which can be used to access the data contained in a table and otherwise manipulate the table after the table initialization has completed.

Since you are using *DataTable* you already have an API instance  , so try this

```
$datatable.api().row.add([
   item[i][0],
   item[i][1]
]).draw();
```

EDIT:
you need to initialize it like this

```
var $dataTable = $('#datatable-keytable').dataTable({
  keys: true
});
```

You can also use `retrive`

> DataTables as a retrieve option which can be used to tell DataTables that you are aware that the initialisation options can't be changed after initialisation, and that should that occur, that you just want the DataTable instance to be returned.

```
var $datatable = $('#datatable-keytable');

$datatable.DataTable( {
  retrieve: true
} ).row.add([
              item[i][0],item[i][1]
           ]).draw();
```

Comment: I get the initialization error again, see my updated code above.

Comment: this means  you have duplicate stuff